# How to combine network load balancers in eks?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, kubernetes-service, aws-nlb

I have an EKS with fargate alone setup with 3 microservices exposed via NLB each using AWS Load balancer controller to the API Gateway using the VPC links for REST APIs. I was asked to maintain a single LB for the three services.

So I have tried the ALB using ingress but the problem is that VPC links for REST APIs cannot be formed with ALBs.

I have manually tried to remove the target groups from the rest of the load balancers and added them to new listener ports to a single NLB, it worked with API Gateway.

**I am not sure if this is the correct way.** **Is there any other way to combine the NLBs in EKS**?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Coud you provide your configuration files? It is important to reproduce your problem.  
Have you watched the [NLB on Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html) and there are examples there.

Comment: Kubernetes version 1.21 is used and eksctl is used to setup, I do not understand which configuration files are needed.
Steps to reproduce my problem,
1. create 2 pods say nginx and apache along with their services
2. Make one service as nlb say nginx
3. Now to find how to use nlb for both nginx and apache having listeners on 2 ports